# Understanding Reduce() function exception: Unsupported combination of input and output array formats

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and i wanted to learn how to use the function reduce() properly.

Description of the function in OpenCVSharp: https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/7bb05237-7ff6-0e19-bfeb-36ea352b3051.htm

I've created a custom Mat object and applied the Reduce function on it.

```
        int[,] mat2d = new int[,] 
        { 
            { 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0 },
        };
        Mat testMat = new Mat(4, 14, MatType.CV_32S, mat2d);
        Mat reducedMat = testMat.Reduce(ReduceDimension.Row, 
                                           ReduceTypes.Sum, 
                                           MatType.CV_32S);
```

I'm expecting that reducedMat will be a 1d array where each element at index i contains the sum of row i in testMat.

Unfortunatly i get an expception "OpenCVException: Unsupported combination of input and output array formats".

I've also tried to change the ReduceDimension parameter and dtype parameter to every possible option, but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is replacing `int[,] mat2d` with `byte[,] mat2d`.

It turns out `int` is not a valid type for reduce.